# My AMD A8-4500M is at 120C Is this a error with speccy

Tags: cpu, gpu, cooling, temperature, overheating

I just installed speccy on my laptop and was very surprised to see these temperatures when idling
[image: high temps]

My CPU has a maximum temperature of 100C and the fan is quiet (and is working) and my laptop doesn't so hot and is not overheating.Also Linux (elementary OS) reports 55C idle and 89C while doing some intensive work.So could this be a speccy problem or is my cpu actually that hot.

Also the integrated GPU temps are good and both the CPU and GPU are on the same chip so the GPU should also be hot

EDIT : HWMonitor also reports the same temperature

Comment: 120 is the kind of temperature that it should reboot at, in fact an amd cpu is set to reboot in HW around 80 90 degrees. did you search for people with similar issues? it could be a motherboard sensor, if linux sais normal temps it's a software error somewherein the PC. search for same issue with that HW SW config online.

Comment: That's definitely not normal, but I doubt it's anything wrong with the applications. I'd point my finger at Windows first, if anything. If Linux shows the laptop being much cooler, then move Windows into the spotlight, as from personal experience, I've noticed Windows 10 reports things wrong. side note (and off topic): what is that background?

Comment: Other computers I have report normal temperature below 90c. They run Windows 10 but are Intel

Comment: Also I can see that other components such as the motherboard aren't hot

Comment: 123C is the type of number you see when an overflow problem.  123C is 253F which is 2 off from 255 which is the maximum for a 8-byte number.  *I suspect the sensor is the problem for that reason.*

Comment: It is not always 123.It gets as low as 108 and as high as around 130

Comment: A search online shows that this problem is common with my CPU and laptops the same brand (HP)